# Is there way to hide the edges in a network graph in R?

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking, network-analysis

What i want is resp 1 and 3 separate nodes but without the edge lines[image]

Comment: Just set `edge.color = NA`.

Comment: Thanks it works but do you know how can reproduce 3 nodes of 1 instead of just 1. There are 3 edge lines to 1. so i want 3 separate nodes of 1

Comment: You will have to split the node into 3 nodes, maybe with the same label, but different nodes.